# Unexpected end of JSON input - Retrieving Data from server issue

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am trying to create a page whereby you can submit some text and then retrieve it on button press, I have managed to get it to submit to my server, however on retrieval I keep getting the error "unexpected end of JSON input" and have no idea what to do about it, my knowledge of PHP/JSON is very limited, any criticism / pointers are greatly appreciated.

JS:

```
function writeDoc() {
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "gethint.php";
var input = document.getElementById("text").value;
var clicker = document.getElementById("submit");

xhttp.open("POST", "gethint.php", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        alert("DataSubmitted");
    }
  }
    xhttp.send("input= " + input);
  } 

function readDoc() {
var xxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();   
xxhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        alert(data);
    }
  }
   xxhttp.open("GET", "gethint2.php", true);
   xxhttp.send();
}
```

PHP/HTML:

```
<php? session_start(); ?>
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Text Input To Save: </label>
    <br></br>
    <textarea rows="6" cols="20" id="text" name="textInput"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" onclick="writeDoc()">
    <br></br>
    <label>Retrieve Text :</label> <input type="button" id="getText" 
  onclick="readDoc()">
  </body>

 </html>
```

Sending Data:

```
<?
  $_SESSION["input_data"] = $_POST;
  echo $_POST["input"];
?>
```

Retrieving Data:

```
<?php
  $_SESSION["input_data"] = json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: Where is this magical JSON? Post it...

Comment: It's within the PHP code isn't it?

Comment: _It's within the PHP code isn't it?..._ Huh? What php code? Post the json that seems to be invalid... it should be the response of your JS code 'this.responseText'

Comment: You got a problem on the first line by the way. You have to open your PHP tag like this: `<?php`

Comment: @B00 that refers to whatever the text input of the user was, I apologise if I'm being a bit retarded, I'm  extremely new to this.